# UINavigationcontroller: Use a button to jump to other uiview from the tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, android-mapview

I havent tried this, yet. So is a kind of theoretical question.

I have a tabbarcontroller, and in one view, let us call it "stages", i want to have a button that give you a shortcut to the next tab bar item that is a mapview. In the mapview have I lot of annotations pins, that represent the position of several stages.

Resuming, I want a button in the stages view that jump directly to the annotation pin in the mapview in the next tabbar item.

Should I use like normally the [navigationcontroller pushcontroller: animated:] or exist other method to do it? In last case I will use normally push to another mapview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to directly jump to the other tab (you don't want a new viewcontroller in your navigationController, but want the other tab's VC), you can create a button or whatever that sets the `selectedViewController` property of your `UITabBarController` to the viewController in the other tab. (if your tabbarcontroller has constant tabs (they dont get changed)) you can do this by using the `UITabBarController`'s `viewControllers` array. Something like this should work:

```
-(IBAction) jumpToMapTab:(id)sender {

    myTabBarController.selectedViewController = [[myTabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:indexOfMyMapTab];

}
```

`

Comment: Looks like neat solution, but I have a completely custom UITabbarcontroller. And actually is not responding to hard code which object in the array it will select.

Comment: But I found a workaround that was quite similar. I reached my custom tabbar methods for selectedviewcontroller through the AppDelegate. So now is responding and jumping to the mapview. Then is left how to find a specific annotation in the mapview.